# My javascript google maps works by itself, but not when I post it into my website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am stumped with google maps api because I am not very savvy with javascript. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/wide.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Orange Lizards - Atlanta, GA</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<br />
<table width="865" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="images/header_logo.png" width="865" height="156" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" style="padding-left: 20px;"><div align="center" class="whiteThirteenBold"><a href="index.html" class="white">HOME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="our_contractors.html" class="white">OUR CONTRACTORS&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="contact_us.html" class="white">CONTACT US</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="wol1_concept.html" class="white">WHY ORANGE LIZARDS</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="629" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Body" -->
      <p class="splash2">Map Wide</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmryDuU2lmu2kImnSi8UbrVog3ynxYC_k&sensor=false"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

html, body { height: 400px; width: 500px; } 

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

//<![CDATA[

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {

    zoom: 12,

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.805932,-84.340582),

    mapTypeControl: true,

    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},

    navigationControl: true,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),

                                myOptions);



  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.close();

        });

  setMarkers(map, beaches);

}

var icons = new Array();

icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://orangelizards.com/images/mapicons/trim_logo.png",

      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.

      new google.maps.Size(40, 40),

      // The origin for this image is 0,0.

      new google.maps.Point(0,0),

      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.

      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {

   if ((typeof(iconColor)=="undefined") || (iconColor==null)) { 

      iconColor = "red"; 

   }

   if (!icons[iconColor]) {

      icons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://orangelizards.com/images/mapicons/"+ iconColor +".png",

      // This marker is 40 pixels wide by 40 pixels tall.

      new google.maps.Size(40, 40),

      // The origin for this image is 0,0.

      new google.maps.Point(0,0),

      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.

      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

   } 

   return icons[iconColor];



}

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y

  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located

  // in the top left of the image.



  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker

  // increase in the X direction to the right and in

  // the Y direction down.



  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/trim_logo.png',

      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.

      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),

      // The origin for this image is 0,0.

      new google.maps.Point(0,0),

      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.

      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',

      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension

      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.

      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),

      new google.maps.Point(0,0),

      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.

      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which

      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final

      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first

      // coordinate.

  var iconShape = {

      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],

      type: 'poly'

  };

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(

  { 

    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)

  });



function createMarker(map, latlng, label, html, color) {

    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: latlng,

        map: map,

        shadow: iconShadow,

        icon: getMarkerImage(color),

        shape: iconShape,

        title: label,

        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5

        });



    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 

        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        });

}



/**

 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for

 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each

 * other.

 */

var beaches = [

  ['Trim Logo', 33.806431,-84.338436, "trim_logo"],

  ['RPS Logo', 33.805932,-84.340582, "RPS_logo"],

  ['<a href="http://google.com>Test Test</a>', 33.805147,-84.338565, "rmi_logo"],

];



function setMarkers(map, locations) {

  // Add markers to the map



  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var beach = locations[i];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);

    var marker = createMarker(map,myLatLng,beach[0],beach[0],beach[3]);

  }

}

//]]>

</script> 

</head> 

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> 

<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

_uacct = "UA-162157-1";

urchinTracker();

</script>

</body> 

    <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
    <td><div align="center" class="bodyWhite">Copyright &copy; 2012 Orange Lizards Atlanta </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

The script works fine when it is in an html file by itself, but doesn't display when I post it on my site. Any ideas? Also, when I add more than 5 markers it seems to mess up. I am bad with javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could post a smaller code sample that reproduced the problem. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx

Comment: There is no smaller code. The only way I know how to reproduce the problem is by pasting the script into the website because the script itself works fine when its in a separate .html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the API key (see the part of your code where it says src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=**AIzaSyCmryDuU2lmu2kImnSi8UbrVog3ynxYC_k**&sensor=false" ). The API key is host-specific, so if a key was issued for "localhost" the same key will not work for "orangelizards.com". You either need to request a new key from Google or switch to the new version of the Google Maps API which does not require a key. Also, as commenter "epascarello" pointed out, it would help if you posted the exact error you see in the Javascript console.